# Motion tracking in After Effects 2020 (as well as in 2019) becomes very slow after some time

Tags: after-effects, tracking, performance

When I perform motion tracking by 2 points in AE 2020 it starts with good acceptable speed (10-15 fps) and then after about 1000-2000 frames it sometimes become very slow, about 1 fps.
The video has 4K resolution, 60fps.

I have pretty good computer:
Core i5-7600k, 1080ti, 48Gb RAM, SSD

And also I see in task manager as well in HWmonitor that each CPU core is not loaded more than 50%, GPU is used by 0-3%, memory usage can be not more that 50% of memory assigned to Adobe products, disk usage can be 0. GPU memory usage about 30-50%. I have a separate 500Gb SSD for caches only and I assigned 350Gb for adobe cache in AE settings. The disk is almost empty, so there are about 400Gb free space when slowness is occured.

So why this slowness in motion tracking happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but this sounds like either a After-Effects bug (like so many other bugs) or it has something to do with your footage, as it might become harder to analyze after some time. Have you tried the same with another clip?

Comment: yes, I tried this with 5 clips and this bug appears on each of them

Comment: I see, this is odd. Have you tried using the Mocha tracker? It comes free with after-effects since it got introduced to it a few versions back.